# Numbering sequentially where two columns are similar

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a list of file numbers in column A, date of service in column C, and TIN numbers in column G. I have the list sorted by file number small to largest and then date of service small to largest.

I need to order the tin numbers 1 through x for how ever many times a TIN shows up in a given file number. for example in file number 123aaa the hypothetical tin 78657832 shows up 3 times, however the tins are in G1, G9, and G22. I would want to number those 1, 2 and 3. I have over 300 file numbers as well so the function needs to be contained within each file number.

i assume part of the function would be IF(A3=A2,IF(... but i can't figure out how to then number the tin numbers when they are all in different cells

also, right now the TINs are in File and date of service order and i'd like to keep it that way, the number 1 would be the first instance that TIN was seen in the file number

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? A screenshot would probably help.

Comment: You may want to look into `COUNTIF`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted it a few different ways then put a number 1 in i1 where I was going to put the counts, did something like 
IF(A2=A1,IF(C2=C1,i1,i+1),1) and it looks good after I dragged it down